# getting an error while starting normal main activity

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am currently breaking my head off, because I can start a normal `startActivity()`. It is always giving me this error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread
>   android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object
>   reference

I am starting it from my Application
Welcome Activity:

```
application.getUserFromDatabase(getApplicationContext(), username, password);
```

Application:

```
public void getUserFromDatabase(Context context, String username, String password) {
   //new GetFromDatabase().execute("getUser.php", "?username=" + username + "&password=" + password, this, context);
    WelcomeActivity activity = new WelcomeActivity();
    activity.startMainActivity();
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.mydomain.app">

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you in advance :)

EDIT:
I forgot adding my Method startMainActivity here:

```
public void startMainActivity(){
    Intent startMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class)
    startActivity(startMain);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code in the welcome activity please

Comment: Can you provide more detail on the code under WelcomeActivity activity = new WelcomeActivity(); activity.startMainActivity(); what's the code inside startMainActivity

Comment: @RishabhJain Yes please refer to my Edit.

Comment: In addition to @Farrokh Shahriari's answer below, you cant's start an activity using the application context. You need to give the activity/service context when creating an intent.

Answer (score 0):

you must use intent for startActivity();

example:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
 startActivtiy(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

It definitely causing you a null pointer exception because your `WelcomeActivity` is not created yet. You can't start an activity by creating a new instance of Activity with:

```
WelcomeActivity activity = new WelcomeActivity();
```

Your activity need to be start with:

```
Intent welcome = new Intent(context, WelcomeActivity.class);
context.startActivtiy(welcome);
```

or by adding the correct intent-filter so the activity will be launched by the Android system.

You can start your activity from Application with something like this:

```
// FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is required
// FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP brings back to the top of the stack
Intent mainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(mainActivity);
```

Though I think you should not start an Activity via Application. You need to think throughly about your design so there is no activity connection with the application.